# Mysql restore failed due to utf-8 issue

Tags: mysql, database-restore

This is my guess. The restore stopped at the line where the UTF-8 charactors appeared which is some non-English charators. So it messed up the whole process.

I want to restore database through a SQL file which I dumped from another database. The other database is using all utf-8. See the second part.

Can anyone tell me the dump commmand and restore command which takes this issue into account?

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation_%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | gbk_chinese_ci  |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | gbk_chinese_ci  |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'character_set_%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                  |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | gbk                                    |
| character_set_connection | gbk                                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                 |
| character_set_results    | gbk                                    |
| character_set_server     | gbk                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                   |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The server SQL dump file came from:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character_set_%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                            |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                             |
| character_set_connection | utf8                             |
| character_set_database   | utf8                             |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                           |
| character_set_results    | utf8                             |
| character_set_server     | utf8                             |
| character_set_system     | utf8                             |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'collation_%';
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

when creating database select utf general using phpmysql, and it should do the job,

Comment: New database is created in UTF8 charset and collation, I think.

Comment: i don't have access to create new database right now else I could tell you which one to select, I had this problem few years back, i switched one utf to another and it worked

Comment: I tried phpmyadmin and it worked. Strangely, it failed in command line.

Comment: thanks for replaying letting me know that it worked, please +1 and accept it as answer if it helped, thanks

Comment: Your anwswer solved the problem but it's a get-around solution. Maybe we can wait a bit longer to see a solution to solve my command line problem. Because I can't work with phpmyadmin. That's for small amount of data.